# JQuery Index number of LI which has a class, then count another UL and assign a class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a custom made accordion using a ul. I also have a counter at the top to show which section of the accordion you are in. Ie. 1-2-3-4-5 and they are highlighted depending on which li of the accordion you are in.

I am trying to get the index of the accordion LI which has the class 'activeform' and then assign an 'active' class to the counter UL li which corresponds.

I've done lots of searching for a resolve but i'm not sure if I've got it right. It certainly isn't working!

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
if($('.form-accordion li').hasClass('activeform')) {
                var number = $(this).index();
                if(number == $('.number-list li').index()) {
                    $('.number-list li').addClass('active');
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you have is `this` reference in the `if` handler, that does not refer to the `li.activeform` element. Also your second `if` condition is wrong as it would return `0` for the index.

You need to get the index of `li.activeform` based on its siblings so use `$('.form-accordion li.activeform').index()`, then use that to get the correct `.number-list li` element

```js
var idx = $('.form-accordion li.activeform').index();
if (idx >= 0) {
  $('.number-list li.active').removeClass('active'); //only if you want to remove the previous active class here
  $('.number-list li').eq(idx).addClass('active');
}
```

```css
.active,
.activeform {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="form-accordion">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li class="activeform">3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="number-list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working when I use it. Could it be because the activeform class is assigned by jQuery further up the page? It is removed and re-assigned when you click on the accordions too. Cheers

Comment: In fact on closer inspection it is removing the active class from number-list and then re-adding it onto number 1....

Comment: Got it working! Thanks. I just put the whole thing in the jQuery that runs the accordian - the click function. All making sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq) like below:

```
var number = $('.form-accordion li.activeform').index();
$('.number-list li').eq(number).addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.number-list li').removeClass('active');
$('.number-list li:eq('+$('.form-accordion li.activeform').index()+')').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer